# How to configure Java Spring Boot OAuth2/OIDC Authoriation Server to be able to login from an other host?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-authorization-server

I do not want to use the built-in default login page of Spring Security, I want to use an Angular project instead. But I am stacking at a point or maybe I misunderstood how the OAuth2/OIDC works.

**The current stack looks like this:**

- http://localhost:9000 - Java Spring Boot OAuth2/OIDC Authorization Server
- http://localhost:4200 - Angular app (with angular-oauth2-oidc library)
- http://localhost:3000 - Angular app to serve the login form (username + password)

**Workflow:**
1., The user opens the app at `http://localhost:4200`
2., It fetches the Discover Document at `http://localhost:9000/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Discovery Document looks like this:

```
{
  "issuer": "http://localhost:9000",
  "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize",
  "device_authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/device_authorization",
  "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token",
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "client_secret_jwt",
    "private_key_jwt"
  ],
  "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/jwks",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/connect/logout",
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code"
  ],
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
  ],
  "revocation_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/revoke",
  "revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "client_secret_jwt",
    "private_key_jwt"
  ],
  "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/introspect",
  "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "client_secret_jwt",
    "private_key_jwt"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid"
  ]
}
```

3., It fetches the JWKS at `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/jwks` - **200 OK, but response is empty**
4., Calls the /authorize endpoint (GET `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=default-client&state=UG5sNVg3UFk3b3FBeUNFQkY5NG41ZXdlelpsek82UzJpN2hVX3RQeTl1MFd2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fgame&scope=openid%20profile&code_challenge=cN_jQUuH5ebleoNirAZZqCWkL1tp3vUP67070td0hbg&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=UG5sNVg3UFk3b3FBeUNFQkY5NG41ZXdlelpsek82UzJpN2hVX3RQeTl1MFd2`)
5., Response: 302 and contains `Location: http://localhost:3000/login` header, so it redirects me to the login page, which is fine... but I do not see the required query params or I do not know why http://localhost:9000/oauth2/jwks response is empty.

```
package rpc.authorizationserver;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import rpc.authorizationserver.user.CustomUserDetailsService;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.UUID;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfiguration(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions ->
                        exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("http://localhost:3000/login")))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                        oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(x -> x.loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login"));

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("content-type");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {

        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient
                .withId("default-client-oidc")
                .clientId("default-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:4200/game")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:3000/login")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("data.read")
                .scope("data.write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build()).build();

        logger.info("###########" + oidcClient.toString());

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
}
```

6., Would be the user enters username and password and call /token endpoint.

What is wrong with the current implementation?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible sample that includes client and login components? Your expectation for #6 seems to be incorrect, but it's hard to tell without seeing code.